# Error "object has no attribute" With classes

Tags: python

Hi I am having a problem with a code I wrote. I am trying to make a class and import it to another file but a error keeps coming up. Here is my code:

File1 (With class):

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, Number, employeeName, Address, Wage, Time):
        self.Staff = self
        self.employeeNum = Number
        self.Name = employeeName
        self._Address = Address
        self.Wage = Wage
        self.workTime = Time

    def getInfo():
        return(_employeeNum,__Address)

    def setInfo(newNumber):
        if newNumber > 6:
            self._employeeNum = newNumber
```

File2(Importing class):

```
from Project7 import Employee as e

Emp1 = e.__init__("Employee", "6765", "John", "123 Baker Street", 13.00, 15)

print(Employee)
print(Emp1)
```

I am not sure what is happening and any info would be really helpful! Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to remove self.Staff = self . self is the object, what is the pourpose of your code on that part? Also on getInfo() and setInfo() should go to self.variables

Comment: get_info needs self in both the definition and the return for the variables. set info needs it in the definition.

Comment: also your constructor for employee is being passed "Employee" in the place of Number etc.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to explicitly call `__init__` method.

You can simply run:

```
Emp1 = e("Employee", "6765", "John", "123 Baker Street", 13.00, 15)
```

then, you renamed Employee class as "e": so print(Employee) will raise an error, because name "Employee" does not exist.

I also suggest to follow Python conventions for naming classes and variables:
Capital for classes
lowercase for variables

```
from Project7 import Employee

emp1 = Employee("Employee", "6765", "John", "123 Baker Street", 13.00, 15)
```